# Do all object-oriented languages create a lot of duplicate information in memory?

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, oop

I am reading a book about JS and other web stuff now and that's what I encountered about the prototype keyword:

> The prototype keyword can save you a lot of memory. In the User class, every instance will contain the three properties and the method. Therefore, if you have 1,000 of these objects in memory, the method showUser will also be replicated 1,000 times. However, because the method is identical in every case, you can specify that new objects should refer to a single instance of the method instead of creating a copy of it.

Don't any object-oriented language behaves just like this? I have read some books about C++, C# and never been told about that. I think it follows to create static methods in class and call them from not static methods, or it is not a problem in other languages and I should not even remember about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Prototypes](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/prototype.html#the-prototype-language-paradigm) is a very different way of doing OOP.

With this paradigm, objects contain both code and data. That's why if you duplicate your objects thousands of times, there will be thousands of copies of the methods. In the more common inheritance paradigm, classes only have a reference to their methods, the method is outside the objects.

Very few languages follow this paradigm, but Javascript is one of them. Most OOP languages, like C# or C++, don't have the kind of prototypes you're talking about, so they don't have this particular problem.

Comment: But why to hold both code and data? It seem unreasonable to me. Which benefits it gives?

Comment: @usersample It's just a different way to view OOP. Here state is completely contained in the object, in a way that's even more OOP than other regular languages.

Comment: I am not very tempted in JS, but may be it's possible to change object's methods and structure outside initial definition? And then containing complete state in object seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

In C# and other statically typed langauges, the methods each class users are defined once and then each instantiation of that object refers only to the single definition. As such, there is no need for the same construct as the prototype in JS.